# Cannot find namespace error

Tags: typescript

I have the following setup:

```
// enums.ts
export enum DocumentType {
  Email = 0,
  Unknown = 1
}
```

-

```
// remote.ts
/// <reference path="./remote.d.ts" />
import enums = require('./enums');

class Remote implements test.IRemote {
  public docType: enums.DocumentType;

  constructor() {
    this.docType = enums.DocumentType.Unknown;
  }
}

export = Remote;
```

-

```
// remote.d.ts
import * as enums from './enums';


declare module test {
  export interface IRemote { 
    docType: enums.DocumentType;
  } 
}
```

But when I run tsc over this I get `Cannot find namespace 'test'` from remotes.ts. What am I missing?

Other information that might be useful: I've recently upgraded from Typescript 1.5 to Typescript 1.8 and replaced the use of const enums with plain enums as in the example.

Answer (score 4):

You need to export the internal module from `remote.d.ts` as well:

**remote.d.ts**

```
import * as enums from './enums';

export declare module test {
    export interface IRemote { 
        docType: enums.DocumentType;
    } 
}
```

This is because you have the external module `remote` (the file itself is the module when there is a top-level `import` or `export` statement), from which types and other symbols are available when they are exported, much like how `IRemote` is exported from module `test`.

In other words, you have an internal module inside an external module, but the internal module is not exported. Also, the IRemote interface is effectively double wrapped, and would qualify for the fullname `remote.test.IRemote`.

---

Note: IMO, mixing internal modules and external modules in the same project can lead to many issues and inconveniences if you are not careful and as such, should be avoided when possible.

Comment: If I add the export in d.ts I get the same error. If I change remote.ts to implement remote.test.IRemote I get an error cannot find namespace 'remote'

Comment: @AndrewJones What's your syntax for importing `remote.test`?

Comment: I'm in remote.ts and the interface is defined in remote.d.ts other than the ///<reference path="./remote.d.ts />" I'm not doing anything. Other than adding the export in remote.d.ts and then adding remote.test.IRemote in the implements statement I've made no other changes to the above code.

Comment: @AndrewJones I mean, where and how do you `import` the remote module definition file?

Comment: Well, I guess I'm not. So are you implying that I should have something like: `import remote = require('./remote');` inside remote.ts? I thought I only needed the reference tag.

Comment: @AndrewJones Yes, although not the `.d.ts`, but the actual file containing the types themselves.

Comment: But that's `remote.ts` which references the `.d.ts` file. I'm expecting to be able take a class that implements an interface and then rather than have the interface in the same file, move it to a `someclass.d.ts` file and reference it. And I expect that to be fully contained. Is this not correct? Internal modules do complicate but that's the gist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105131/discussion-between-andrew-jones-and-john-white).

Comment: what is the difference between "export declare module" and "export module"??

Answer (score 2):

In my universe `Cannot find namespace` error is CLI service thing that goes away after restarting npm watcher.